# Saving external JSON to database (RAILS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

i'm trying to save external values from BitBucket to my Rails app and then return them in view(i'm new with databases), so if somebody can help me with that, i'll really appreciate it.

I returned API call from BitBucket in my controller so its works well.. Then i create model **`bitbucket name:string message:text date:integer`**

So now i place this into **`bitbucket.rb`** model:

```
class Bitbucket < ActiveRecord::Base
    def saveData
        require 'bitbucket_rest_api'   
          bitbucket = BitBucket.new login:'...', password:'...'

          repo = bitbucket.repos.commits.list '...', '...'
          data = repo["values"]

            data.each do |r|
                r["author"]["user"]["display_name"]
                r["message"]
                DateTime.strptime(r["date"], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').strftime("%D %r")
            end
    end
end
```

This is the first call what i want to save into DB then i would like to save every new commit into database.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should name methods in Ruby like this: `save_data`, not `saveData` to anything else.
2. Your method should be class-method since you are not using any object inside of it.
3. You can create database entry with `create` or `new`, `save` chain.

This might help:

```
class Bitbucket < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.save_data
    require 'bitbucket_rest_api'   
    bitbucket = BitBucket.new login:'...', password:'...'
    repo = bitbucket.repos.commits.list '...', '...'
    repo["values"].each do |r|
      create(
        name: r["author"]["user"]["display_name"],
        message: r["message"],
        date: DateTime.strptime(r["date"], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').strftime("%D %r")
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: And Controller gonna be like `@commits = Bitbucket.all` ?
Then in view `<%= @bitbucket.name %>` etc.. ?

Comment: @LiborZahrádka `@commits.name` For example.

Comment: Yeah sorry wrong variable.. i did a mistake.. ok thanks a lot

Comment: `bitbucket.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' message: r["message"]` and `bitbucket.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end date: DateTime.strptime(r["date"],...`
`bitbucket.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end`

Im getting this error right now

Comment: @LiborZahrádka Updated my answer.

Comment: And how to execute that code to seed the db? @MaximPontyushenko

Comment: Did you try JSON.parse(repo["values"])?

Comment: I were doing this directly in controller but it worked.. But i cant figured out why db is still empty

Comment: @LiborZahrádka Did you call `Bitbucket.save_data`?

Comment: Yeah i did that but im getting this error : `NoMethodError: undefined method 'save_data' for #<Class:0x000000038794b8>`

Comment: Is there any way how to update that database constatly (every 1 hour)..? I tried to used [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) , but it's wrote whole DB again so there is duplicate..